# Give a generating function for the number of ways for her to choose outfits. EXPLAIN how you model the problem.

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

Mrs X must choose outfits for each day of the coming week, that is, she must decide on an outfit for Monday,
Tuesday, and so on (7 days). She has 20 out ts to choose from and she does not want to wear any outfit
more than twice.

Give a generating function for the number of ways for her to choose outfits. EXPLAIN how you model the
problem.

I have attempted the question and I have attached my working out as an image. I know I should get the coefficient of x^20 but I don't think I will get to that power with my answer. Is my solution correct? [picture of my solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kg3R.jpg)

My solution is x^7(1+x/2)^7

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: Please see the **Edit-Images** section in [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).